# The parent widget is rerendering after changing the the state of the child through provider

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to hide the bottom navigation bar when the sliding panel is moved down.
But on changing the value of the child from provider the parent widget and child widget is re-rendering.
here the parent widget->

bottomprovider.dart

```
class BottomNavigationBarProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  get currentIndex => _currentIndex;
  bool _navbarhide = false;
  /*  void changestate() {
    navbarhide = true;
    notifyListeners();
  } */
  get navbarhide => _navbarhide;
  set navbarhide(bool sett) {
    _navbarhide = sett;

    notifyListeners();
    print(_navbarhide);
  }

  set currentIndex(int index) {
    _currentIndex = index;
    print("Changing page index");
    notifyListeners();
    print(currentIndex);
  }
}
}
```

homepage

```
class _OrbitAppPageStateState extends State<OrbitAppPageState> {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var provider = Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context);
 final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Scaffold(
body: currentTab[provider.currentIndex],
bottomNavigationBar: provider._navbarhide
          ? null
          : Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                    spreadRadius: 50,
                    blurRadius: 5,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
)
}

}
```

changing the boolean from the child and sending it to homepage through provider.

this is **dashboard.dart** which is child

```
lass _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard>
   with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
 //list of circular widgets

 bool sliderOpened = true;
 bool toggle = false;
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   var provider = Provider.of<BottomNavigationBarProvider>(context,
       listen: false) /* listen: true) */;
   goog(bool sel) {
     provider.navbarhide = sel;
   }
return Scaffold(
SlidingUpPanel(
       minHeight: 135,
       defaultPanelState: PanelState.OPEN,
       onPanelSlide: (double) {
         setState(() {
           sliderOpened = true;
         });
       },
       onPanelClosed: () {
         goog(true);
         setState(() {
           sliderOpened = false;
         });
       },
       onPanelOpened: () {
         goog(false);
         setState(() {
           sliderOpened = true;

           /*      provider.navbarhide = false; */
         });
       },
)

}

}
```